# How to use commands in AWS EC2 elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I am trying to fix a problem I have with my program I uploaded to AWS in elastic beanstalk tomcat. I found someone who seems to have had a similar problem, but I can't find where I execute their solution.

[AWS EC2 tomcat permission denied creating/writing to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630698/aws-ec2-tomcat-permission-denied-creating-writing-to-file?rq=1)

The answer said that I should use the following commands:

```
    chmod o+x /home
    chmod o+x /home/ec2-user
```

I want to see if this will fix my problem, however I have looked everywhere and have found no information regarding where I actually put these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem fixed if you run those commands manually? (i.e. `eb ssh` into your instance and then `sudo chmod o+x /home` then `sudo chmod o+x /home/ec2-user`)

If so, you could automate running those commands using an EB extension file. The documentation is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) but it would look something like this:

**.ebextensions/01-fix-permissions.config**

```
commands:
  fix_home_permissions:
    command: "chmod o+x /home"
  fix_ec2user_permissions:
    command: "chmod o+x /home/ec2-user"
```

Comment: After reading through some more documentation here is my understanding of one way I could set up and include those commands. Add a folder called .ebextensions in my maven project in eclipse. Create a .config file and put it in this folder. Run maven install to get the .war file and then update my AWS web app with the new file.

Comment: Yes, if you create `.ebextensions/01-fix-permissions.config` and then deploy your WAR it should do what you want.

Comment: I tried uploading my war file as I previously described and am still getting the same error. Does the .war not include these changes? Do I need to create a .zip instead to include them?

Comment: Update: tried as a .zip and also have the same error

Comment: If you run the `chmod` commands manually, does your original problem go away? If so, please post your `/var/log/eb-activity.log`.

Comment: Where do I go to run them manually? Also, I came back to AWS this morning and found that it actually was not the same. Apparently I tested it before it was entirely finished deploying. In AWS "recent events" it says `The configuration file __MACOSX/.ebextensions/._01-fix-permissions.config in application version ARFormzip contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: unacceptable character '&#0;' (0x0) special characters are not allowed in "<reader>", position 0, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (&#0;) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.`

Comment: My file contains exactly what you posted in the answer right now.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed my formatting problem in accordance to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924236/mac-zip-compress-without-macosx-folder) Now I get an error that is gives practically no information at all: HTTP status 404 Type: status report Message: /_ Description: the requested resource is not available. :(

Comment: You can try executing the commands manually by using `eb ssh` to log into your instance and running `sudo chmod o+x /home` and `sudo chmod o+x /home/ec2-user`.

Comment: Got it. Not fixing the issue so I'm going to need to continue searching for the bug. Do I have to do these commands in EB CLI everytime I upload an updated war file in order for them to continue to apply?

Comment: If you run the commands manually, the effects should persist until the instance is terminated - if a new instance is created (either manually or via auto-scaling) then you'd need to re-run the commands. If you put the commands in `.ebextensions/01-fix-permissions.config`, however, they will be automatically run as part of each deploy.